# Nested model/inline formsets

Tags: django, forms, formsets

I'm working on a page that needs to have a couple levels of editable data. Essentially an entity can have zero to many groups, and each group can have zero to many users. Models as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Platoon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)


class Squad(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    platoon = models.ForeignKey('military.Platoon')


class Soldier(models.Model):
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class SquadMember(models.Model):
    squad = models.ForeignKey('military.Squad')
    soldier = models.ForeignKey('military.Soldier')
```

So in this case, a platoon can have multiple squads, which in turn can have multiple squad members where squad member is a cross reference to a soldier.

When rendering the page, we know which platoon we're looking at, so simply retrieving a list of squads and squad members is easy. The problem is that we need to be able to add/edit/delete a squad on the page as well as adding/deleting members for each squad. I've been trying to wrap my head around the handling of this data for a couple days now, with no real breakthroughs. I keep coming back to thinking it needs to be some sort of nested model formset or perhaps inline formsets, but I haven't been able to find much material on the subject.

Any suggestions on how to approach this one?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You have it pretty much right, your only problem is that django doesn't support nested inline formsets. Fortunately someone has created a django app which allows this in admin: [django-nested-inlines](https://github.com/Soaa-/django-nested-inlines).  I'm using them fairly successfully in my own project.

For your scenario here, you'd set them up along these lines:

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from nested_inlines.admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedTabularInline, NestedStackedInline

from .models import Platoon, Squad, SquadMember


class SquadMemberInlineAdmin(NestedStackedInline):
    model = SquadMember

class SquadInlineAdmin(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Squad
    inlines = [SquadMemberInlineAdmin,]

class PlatoonAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SquadInlineAdmin,]

admin.site.register(Platoon, PlatoonAdmin)
```

You could probably drill this down further by adding Soldier as an inline to SquadMember.

Comment: Thanks, hellsgate! I looked at django-nested-inlines, briefly, a few weeks back; I got the impression that it was only usable within the built-in admin app. Do you know if that's applicable to custom forms as well?

Comment: Sorry, that isn't something I've tried at all.  It may well be possible by extending one of the form classes from nested-inlines rather than the standard ModelForm ubt like I said, I haven't tried it